# GraphX: Wrong output without cache()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm doing the following:

```
var count = 0
while(count > 0){
    val messages = graph.vertices.flatMap{
        // Create messages for other nodes
    }

    // Cache which is critical for the correct execution
    count.cache()
    count = messages.count()

    val msgType1 = messages.filter()
    val msgType2 = messages.filter()


    println(count)
    //Should be exactly messages.count()
    println(msgType1.count() + msgType2.count())
    println("---")
}
```

If I'm executing it exactly like this then the output is:

```
8
6 2
---
11
3 8
---
0
0 0
---
```

which add up exactly to the message count.

If I'm removing the `count.cache()` after the flatMap-operation, then the filtering of the messages is wrong after counting the messages. It looks like the counting clears the messages or something like that.

The output is then:

```
8
0 0
---
0
0 0
---
```

Why is that happening? Is it okay that my program only works if I'm using the cache operation at that point or should it also work without caching the messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, that if `flatmap()` was called once in one loop iteration, then the output was correct.

If it is called twice in one iteration (which could happen, if the messages must be recomputed) then the first output was correct and the following not, because my opertions inside the `flatmap()` can only be executed one time per node and node multiple times.

So if I call `cache()` the flatmap is executed only once. Without cache it is called for every `count()` operation, so the first was correct and the following two wrong.